# Define \pagestyle having "Boxed" Content for Memoir Class

Tags: memoir, box, pagestyle

Please tell me how to design a page (to be coded in the \pagestyle design code) in which only "text area" is boxed. Margins, header and footer must of out of this box. Plus i want to control the thickness and colour of the box.

Thanks,
Satyendra

Answer (score 1):

The following borrows the mechanism to place the frame from the `showframe` package. The `\pagestyle` mechanism isn't really necessary, but just because you asked for it I added it to this. The `framedpage` style doesn't change anything from the current page style (but you could add code that does), but just sets `\myframetrue` so that the frame is displayed. You can control the colour and thickness by redefining `\myframecolor` and `\myframethickness`.

```latex
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myframecolor{\color{purple}}
\newcommand*\myframethickness{.4pt}
\newif\ifmyframe
\pretocmd\pagestyle{\myframefalse}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\newcommand*\mypageframe
  {%
    \begingroup
    \myframecolor
    \linethickness{\myframethickness}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft
      {\framebox(\LenToUnit{\textwidth},\LenToUnit{\textheight}){}}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand*\ps@framedpage{\myframetrue}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\ifmyframe\mypageframe\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments} % only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\duckument
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{framedpage}
\duckument
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}
\duckument
\end{document}
```